# I cannot find CSS position value

Tags: css

[image: css properties and values as seen from chrome dev tools]

I want to change position value -32 to 0 but i am struggling to find the value as i haven't specified it on my code and can't seem to find it on the default browser values. Please see attached picture

Comment: try using "computed" tab (the second tab on your screenshot) where you'd find all the styles and see if it really is set. Also, when you click on desired property, it shows you where it's been set.

Comment: in the image you have the `-32`  on the right because you have `left:0`. if you want it to align to the right, change to `left:auto;right:0`

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help :-) what @Roman suggested best helped in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.main-header`.
Now `.main-header` has a width of 100% + 2rem of the parent, as a result, it is slightly wider and the right position shows -32.

Option #2
Remove `width: 100%` and assign `right: 0`;